# map function on React state - state with fetched API data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import Movie from './Movie';
import axios from 'axios';
import yargsParser from 'yargs-parser';

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [movies, setMovie] = useState([])

  const getMovies = async () => {

    const {data: {data: { movies }}} = await axios.get("https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=rating");
    setMovie([{movies}])
    setLoading(false)

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading ? "we are loading bunch of movies" : movies.map(movie => console.log(movie))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The issue here is that when I check the console, the map function on movies state is returning a single object including all the other objects in it,

[image]

instead of returning all the objects separately. I wonder why? Because of this, when I update the return with the Movie component as below,

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading ? "we are loading bunch of movies" : movies.map(movie => (
        <Movie key={movie.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

and this is how the Movie component looks like

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function Movie({ id, year, title, summary, poster }){
    return <h4>{title}</h4>
}

Movie.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    year: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    summary: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    poster: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

Movie component does not receive the correct props.
I import the prop-types to check it, and it says

[image]

I wonder what should I do with the movies state in order to get the correct props to Movie component?

Comment: FYI, in the first code example, the import react part is not included. but It is there, I copied line after.

Comment: @yoonak pass all properties from map function of Movie that you are receiving in Movie component.

Comment: What do you expect exactly? You passing a prop key and chcking the prop id which is not exists

Comment: @VahidAkhtar yeah that was my initial approach but all of the props throw same error saying "failed prop type, value is undefined".

Comment: I suspect that when you bind movies from the result of the api call, that the key is movies and the value is the array. If you replace with this code : "movies.movies.map(movie => console.log(movie))", you will see you console should log each individual movie

Comment: @yoonvak before iterating through map console your data and check.

Comment: @VincentChinner YES!!!!!!!! as you explained, the key was set to movies! Now it works with your code and I changed the setMovie function without the extra bracket! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (
<div className="App">
  {isLoading ? "we are loading bunch of movies" : movies.movies.map(movie => (
    <Movie key={movie.id} {...movie}/>
  ))}
</div>);
```

Or

```
setMovie(movies)
```

Double check when you bind the array, currently it seems that the key is movies and the value is the array. you want to bind the array directly

Answer (score 0):

You should pass movie as prop

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading ? "we are loading bunch of movies" : movies.map(movie => (
        <Movie key={movie.id} {...movie} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all props to your component)

false code:

```
 <Movie key={movie.id} {...props}/>
```

You can pass whatever this component needs...

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the rest of the data

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading ? "we are loading bunch of movies" : movies.map(movie => (
        <Movie key={movie.id} {...movie}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: rest of the data as in
```
      {isLoading ? "we are loading bunch of movies" : movies.map(movie => (
        <Movie key={movie.id} id={movie.id} year={movie.year} title={movie.title} summary={movie.summary} poster={movie.medium_image_cover}  />
      ))}
```

yeah this was my initial code, but they all throw the same error  "failed prop type, value is undefined"

Comment: As pointed by @Jonas, that might actually causing this issue. You are intializing the state as an array and setting it again inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in the call to `setMovie` - if you want your state to contain the array of movies, you shouldn't create an array with an object inside it, but simply change it to

```
setMovie(movies)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above `Movie` component the result object is not passed as prop to the component. Instead only used map to render component the number of times data present in the array with the unique key passed to the component.

The code can be used as

```
<Movie key={movie.id} {...movie} />
```

OR

```
<Movie key={movie.id} id={movie.id} year={movie.year} title={movie.title} summary={movie.summary} poster={movie.poster} />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const getMovies = async () => {
    const {data: {data: { movies }}} = await axios.get("https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=rating");
    **setMovie([ ...movies ])**
    setLoading(false)
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers